# Smarter way to index loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

I have written a function (call it F) that works "well" (i.e. gives me the result I want) and inside it I call the exact same function (call it G_i) four times (below one of them) except each time I change the way I index my loop to be able to cover all pairs of coefficients in a matrix. I think this method is poor and I would like to know if you have ideas to improve it please...

I do this to check sequentially conditions on the coefficients of a matrix (sometimes in the order (1,2) then (1,3) then (2,3). I go on checking in different orders).

```
function G_1=countbackward(a,,,)
n=a;
G_1=[];


N=1;
while N>0    
for l=n:-1:1 
    for m=1:l

        if some condition on generated matrices
        ...

        elseif  another condition on generated matrices
        ...

        else
            N=0 ;
        end
        G_1=[G_1,g_0] ; 
    end 

end
```

end

(for n=3 I get with the above the entries: (3,1),(3,2),(2,1).)

Other indexing I use with the exact same body of the above function :

```
for l=n:-1:1 
    for m=(l-1):-1:1
```

Same for the following:

```
for l=1:n 
    for m=l+1:n
```

Same for the following:

```
for l=1:n 
    for m=n:-1:l
```

Thank you for your help.

APPENDIX:

below is a simplified example of my code:

```
function H=count2backward(a,g_0,s,e)
%matrix g_0 is the "start" matrix
%matrix g_K is the "end" matrix

n=a; % number of nodes in an undirected graph or size A
s=mypayoff(n,g_0);
e=mypayoff(n,g_K);

H=[];


N=1;
while N>0    
for l=1:n 
    for m=n:-1:l

        if l~=m && g_0(l,m)==0 && s(l)<=e(l) && s(m)<=e(m) && (s(l)<e(l)  || s(m)<e(m) ) ; 
           g_0(l,m)=g_0(l,m)+1 ;
           g_0(m,l)=g_0(m,l)+1 ;
           g_0 ;

           s=mypayoff(n,g_0);

        elseif    l~=m && g_0(l,m)==1 && (s(l)<e(l)  || s(m)<e(m) ) ;
           g_0(l,m)=g_0(l,m)-1 ;
           g_0(m,l)=g_0(m,l)-1 ;
           g_0 ;

           s=mypayoff(n,g_0);

        else
            N=0;

        end
        H=[H,g_0]    ; 
    end  

end
```

end

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank you, I can give my complete code but even in my conditions I call other functions I wrote.. @transversalitycondition

Comment: the point is to try to construct a simple example that illustrates the abstract point so that your question will be of value to other members. the more effort you put into your question, the more effort you can expect in the answer :)

Comment: @transversalitycondition thank u for your advise, I just edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the indexes and pass them as a parameter. That lets you abstract deciding how to loop into another function.

```
indexes = countbackwardpattern(a);
G_1=g_i(a, indexes);
```